# Troubleshooting 'Error: server error' in socket.io chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently working on building a chat app to learn how to utilize socket.io. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm unable to receive emits from the client side. Despite extensive debugging and research, I keep encountering an "Error Server" message.

In my browser's console, the following error is logged:

```less
Connection Failed due to:  Error: server error
    at Socket.onPacket (socket.js:318:33)
    at Emitter.emit (index.mjs:136:20)
    at Polling.onPacket (transport.js:97:28)
    at callback (polling.js:115:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Polling.onData (polling.js:118:53)
    at Emitter.emit (index.mjs:136:20)
    at Request.onLoad (polling.js:361:18)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (polling.js:297:26)
```

To address any potential concerns regarding the network, I have already verified that the transport is being received from the server. Additionally, in my Node.js code, I'm even outputting the message `"user here: " + socket.id` to confirm that the user is connected.

```less
user here :  c7djD9bzpUbwP8dmAAAB
user here :  cqPxsCn-bTbOxfHFAAAC
user here :  OI-bst5WCVPMnNqSAAAD
user here :  YoQg0YBGq5xGGbF8AAAE
user here :  U60NZqgv4NiHsUPoAAAF
user here :  D_93LHCb9z5hbzVjAAAG
```

[image]

Here is my server.js code:

```js
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
require("dotenv").config()
const Server = require("socket.io")
const cors = require("cors")


const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server)
const port = process.env.PORT
const public_directory = path.join(__dirname, "../public")

app.use(express.static(public_directory))
app.use(cors)
io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log("user here : " , socket.id)
  
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));
})

server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port : ${port} `)
})
```

And here is my index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        Chat App
        <!-- <button id="increment" onclick="buttonClicked()">+1</button> -->
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
          const socket = io();

          socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Connected to the server');
          });
        
          socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
            console.log('Connection Failed due to: ', error);
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve the issue I'm facing with socket.io in my chat app. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through your code, it seems to me that you haven't set up any event handlers on the server side to handle the incoming events from the client. In your server.js file, you only have a `disconnect` event handler. You need to also define handlers for the other events that the client may emit.

To receive emits from the client, you need to listen for specific events on the server and then handle them accordingly. Please see the example below

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user here:", socket.id);

  socket.on("chatMessage", (message) => {
    io.emit("chat message", message);
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    io.emit("Chat disconnected");
  })
})
```

In my example above, the server listens for the `chatMessage` event that is emitted by the client. When the message is received, it can then be processed (you can execute some code to maybe save the message in DB or something) and then it is emitted back to all the clients using `io.emit`.

On the client side of things, you can emit the `chatMessage` event with the corresponding message data. See below

```
const socket = io();

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log('Now connected to server');
})

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred with connection', err);
})

// Emitting a chat message
const chatMessage = "Hello world";
socket.emit("chatMessage", chatMessage);
```

So you should be able to receive emits from the client side by setting up these appropriate event handlers. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've used your code , but still getting the same error.
Even handling all the emits, the same error appears.